# Different version of the same iPhone app for 10 different users

Tags: iphone, versions

Is the below requirement possible?

How to make 10 different version of the same iPhone app for 10 different users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Just make the bundle IDs unique, and upload the app 10 different times.

The real question is: Why would you want to?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about Adhoc Distribution. In my opinion, it's not a good way to submit the app 10 times on the App Store, and the possibility for the refuse is very high.

If you need to distribute your app with several versions for several users using Adhoc Distribution, simply create 10 Archives and share the .ipa files to 10 different users (must add their UDID under your Developer Account)

Comment: Hey Thang Tran, How can i create 10 Archives? What does it maean?

Comment: If you don't know about Adhoc Distribution, please check out this link http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

For detail on how to do that, please login your Developer Account Portal and go to the Provisioning Profile part for step-by-step instructions.